# Would rather +( present simple or past simple)

Tags: sentence-construction

John would rather that you not call me tomorrow .

John would rather that you will no call me tomorrow .

Which is the correct sentence and the explanation.....

Comment: In my searching, John would rather that you call me tomorrow is more correct. That is, it means that please, do not call me today.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sentence is correct.

The usual construction after ** would rather that you** is **did (or did not)** call me tomorrow.

However, this depends on the context and construction of the sentence, as illustrated in the examples that you will find below:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner
http://masterkeyenglish.com/id-rather-you-id-prefer-you-to/
https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv107.shtml